# Aws ElasticBeanstalk & CodePipeline Url 404 Not Found

Tags: github, continuous-integration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

So i have a Laravel WebApp on a Github repo, and I have an AWS cicd pipeline using ElasticBeanstalk (EBS) & CodePipeline connected to it.

Now EBS gives me a url to view the webapp but it only shows the homepage of the webapp and nothing else.

[image]

Any idea as to why this is happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: How is Nginx configured?

Comment: its not, the webapp doesnt have a build stage

Comment: But you've got an nginx powered EB environment that can't find your application. It sounds like the first place to look is the nginx config. And without a build stage, how do you package your project for deployment?